# socket exception "access to path is denied"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sockets

I am working on winform application in C# using EF 4. I've made a client and server those can share files. I've given the choice to choose the location where file is to be saved but whether it is selected by user or I hard coded it, result is same the exception.

i done the same thing in cmd based program and it works just fine but in forms it did't work.

I've tried also :

```
string receivedpath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyVideos);
```

Comment: Double check you have permission to that folder?

Comment: i am the admin, is there any other way to check the permission??

Comment: in cmd prog it works just fine

Comment: Try and output that path to a messagebox to confirm its the path your trying to get to. `MessageBox.Show(receivedpath);`